# MSSQL: добавить строку в таблицу и вернуть ее ИД

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

**Добрый день.**

Столкнулся с интересной задачей (MSSQL 2012)-

я в таблицу добавляю запись и пытаюсь вернуть ее ИД (первая колонка таблицы ИД, вторая - строка).

**Есть возможность сделать это одним запросом?**

Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, можно:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (SomeColumn) VALUES ('SomeValue')
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Comment: Если ID нужно выдавать куда-то наружу ( например, в код на C#, ASP и т.д. ), я бы посоветовал впереди ( перед INSERT )  поставить SET NOCOUNT ON;

Answer (score 5):

лучше через OUTPUT

```
CREATE TABLE #t (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), Field1 varchar(10))
Declare @i table (id int)

INSERT INTO #t (Field1) 
OUTPUT inserted.ID INTO @i (id) 
VALUES ('test')

select id from @i
```

Answer (score 3):

Вот в этой ветке https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row хорошо рассказали различные способы.
SCOPE_IDENTITY() может не выдать нужного значения, если есть распараллеливание процессов, во всех остальных случаях его можно использовать.

Цитирую:
"The best (read: safest) way to get the identity of a newly-inserted row is by using the **output** clause. Any other method is not guaranteed to return the correct ID when using parallelism - even if you aren't using parallelism now, writing your SQL like this will ensure you don't have to change it should you move to a parallel environment (e.g. SQL server cluster)."

Comment: проблема с `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` [была исправлена](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2019779) до выхода 2012.

Comment: @PashaPash спасибо, не знала :)