# T-SQL. Как вернуть идентификатор созданной записи?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

Я написал хранимую процедуру которая добавляет данные в таблицу.

```
create procedure AddAddress(@Postcode nvarchar(50),@Region nvarchar(50),@Area nvarchar(50),@City nvarchar(50),@Street nvarchar(50),@House nvarchar(50))
as
begin
insert into Address(Postcode,Region,Area,City,Street,House)
values(@Postcode,@Region,@Area,@City,@Street,@House)
end
```

Не могу разобраться как организовать возврат созданного идентификатора: idAddress. По примеру пробовал:

```
create procedure AddAddress(@Postcode nvarchar(50),@Region nvarchar(50),@Area nvarchar(50),@City nvarchar(50),@Street nvarchar(50),@House nvarchar(50),
@IdAddress int output)
as
begin
insert into Address(Postcode,Region,Area,City,Street,House)
values(@Postcode,@Region,@Area,@City,@Street,@House)
set @IdAddress=idAddress
end
```

Но sql server 2012 ругается и отказывается создавать процедуру.
И еще по возможности поделитесь знаниями как получить этот вывод на стороне приложения на C#. Для подключения я использую SqlConnection. Сама процедура вызывается непосредственно с SqlCommand. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Есть [@@identity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms187342(v=sql.120).aspx) и scope_identity()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ на первую часть вопроса: [MSSQL: добавить строку в таблицу и вернуть ее ИД](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417984/).

Получение output parameter на стороне C#:

```
SqlParameter pvNewId = new SqlParameter();
pvNewId.ParameterName = "@IdAddress";
pvNewId.DbType = DbType.Int32;
pvNewId.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
command.Parameters.Add(pvNewId);

command.ExecuteNonQuery();

var newID = command.Parameters["@IdAddress"].Value;
```

Comment: Можно так же просто после `insert` в процедуре добавить `select scope_identity()` , а затем на клиенте получить это значение   
`var newID = command.ExecuteScalar();`